# Adsense code with heavily negative impact on google pagespeed score

Tags: adsense, pagespeed

After integrating the adsense javascript (adsbygoogle.js) on my website, i loose mobile around 14 points. Check the before after screenshot (88 vs 74 points on mobile).

Google punishes their own scripts?! Does someone of you has a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick solution for that. In my experience Adsense does slow pages down a little, but that's because they have to go through a whole process of auctioning and showing ads.

The real question you should be asking yourself is: does monetization make up for the loss of speed?